# Every modification to class causes error 'Cannot declare class because the name is already in use'

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I've started a Symfony project for an API and have created my first controller

```yaml
# services.yaml
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/EndPoints/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Controller:

```php
namespace App\Controller;
class RegisterController extends AbstractController {
    public function register(Request $request): Response {
         //stuff
    }
}
```

I run this the first time and get an expected result. I do modifications to `RegisterController` and it dies with the error

> Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Controller\RegisterController,
> because the name is already in use

If I go into the `services.yaml` and save it (no modifications) I can run it again with the updated code.

This has only just started happening when I've added `doctrine-test-bundle` and been doing testing however I don't think the two things are related. I've checked my `.env.local` `APP_ENV` is dev. What is causing a cache that means I have to resave `services.yaml` for any change to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the controllers twice.

Here, you are importing all your classes, but your controllers are **not** excluded from auto-wiring:

```yaml
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'
```

And here you import your controller classes again

```yaml
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/EndPoints/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

When the container gets compiled, you end up with a double definition for these classes.

Just do:

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'
            - '../src/EndPoints/'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/EndPoints/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

and you'll be set.

Additionally, you have a PSR-4 mismatch, where the classes at `src/Endpoints` belong to the namespace `Controller`. That's not problematic per-se, but it will only work if your `composer.json` is properly set. Better have directories that match the namespaces, do not make it harder than it should be.

Comment: Thanks that explains it. I only did the EndPoints because I had generic controllers for external systems not associated to end points, it also didn't make sense to have them together. I might change the names a little bit.

Comment: Ok, just pointed that out because I've seen many times errors start appearing down the line because of things like this. Again, with a properly configured autoloader, you can make it work, and I imagine you have it working. But it's good idea to switch it to a simpler PSR-4 compliant structure whenever you can. Good luck!

Comment: Two quick points just for info.  One, changing App\Controller\: to App\EndPoints\: would have fixed the original problem without the need to exclude.  Two, because your controllers extend AbstractController there is not need to explicitly tag them which means you could drop the entire App\Controller section and everything would still work.

Answer (score 0):

From your services.yaml looks like you need to change the controller part.

From

```
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/EndPoints/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

To

```
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

But if you want to put controllers into the EndPoints folder, you need also change the alias in your config.

```
App\EndPoints\:
    resource: '../src/EndPoints/*'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

// controller
namespace App\EndPoints;
class RegisterController extends AbstractController {
    public function register(Request $request): Response {
         //stuff
    }
}
```

And don't forget to change the routing config

Answer (score 0):

you just forget the namespace in the class that you have been created an use it